# How do I return a line conditionally that all other parameters have been met?

Tags: sql

I am wanting to return only tickets that have had all of their tasks closed. Say a ticket has 8 tasks that need to be complete, if all of the tasks are marked as 'CLOSED', then return the parent ticket number with the closed task numbers.

What I have so far is

```
SELECT
phs.ticket,
phs.task_no,
phs.status_code
FROM
table1 phs
WHERE
phs.status_code = ALL (SELECT phs.status_code FROM table1 phs WHERE phs.status_code = 'CLOSED')
AND
phs.ticket <> 'CLOSED'
```

However this only returns tickets where maybe 2 of the 8 tasks are marked as 'CLOSED'.

EDIT1: Per request. This is what a typical ticket looks like:

```
Ticket: A12345    Status: OPEN
---------------------------------
Task 1: B12345    Status: CLOSED
---------------------------------
Task 2: B12346    Status: CLOSED
---------------------------------
Task 3: B12347    Status: OPEN
=================================
Ticket: A54321    Status: OPEN
---------------------------------
Task 1: B54321    Status: CLOSED
---------------------------------
Task 2: B54322    Status: CLOSED
```

The desired result I am looking for would return ticket A54321 as such:

```
Ticket: A54321    Status: OPEN
```

As long as I can return a ticket based on the parent number being OPEN and **all** tasks as CLOSED, that works.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: You mention tickets and tasks but you only use one table `Table1`. So either your model is not clear or your sql is too simplified. Where is the relation between the ticket and it's tasks?

Comment: @TimSchmelter All of the data resides in the one table. Parent ticket#, task#, status code for the parent ticket/tasks, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT phs.ticket,
       phs.task_no,
       phs.status_code
FROM
   table1 phs
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM table1 phs2
    WHERE phs.ticket_no = phs2.ticket_no 
      AND phs2.status_code <> 'CLOSED'
)
AND phs.ticket <> 'CLOSED'
```

Your comment on your question suggested that you have a column `ticket_no`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT
phs.ticket,
phs.task_no,
phs.status_code
FROM
table1 phs
WHERE
phs.ticket <> 'CLOSED'
and exists
(SELECT t.status_code FROM table1 t  WHERE t.status_code = 'CLOSED'
and t.status_code=phs.status_code
group by t.status_code
having count(*)=8 )
```